# How can I change a date field from String to Date or DateTime?

Tags: google-bigquery

I an using Google Big Query and I have a field, named 'AsOfDate' which is set as a string datatype.  I have a bunch of data in this field, which I really want to set as DateTime or just Date.  Either is fine.  I Googled for a solution, and I thought this would be pretty easy to do, but I can't seem to get the data type updated.  I don't want to run a simple select statement; I want to permanently change the Schema.  Has anyone run into this and figured out how to do this kind of thing?  If so, please share your insights.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote directly from the official documentation: '*Changing a column's data type is not supported by the BigQuery web UI, the command-line tool, or the API*.'

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type

> There are two ways to manually change a column's data type:
>
> **Using a SQL query** — Choose this option if you are more concerned about
>   simplicity and ease of use, and you are less concerned about costs.
>
> **Recreating the table** — Choose this option if you are more concerned
>   about costs, and you are less concerned about simplicity and ease of
>   use.

You could use either of the approaches above along with the `PARSE_DATE()` function to transform your string into a date field.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date

Comment: Adding some details about recreating tables. You can run a simple SELECT query and [specify the destination table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#option_2_exporting_your_data_and_loading_it_into_a_new_table_1) to create a new table with the desired schema. This is pretty simple and fit your need to have a permanent table with modified schema.