# All columns have NULLABLE problem when destination table with overwrite preference on Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've running a query to make changes column data type and choose destination table queried table itself.  I  choose  write preferece "Overwrite table". Table all columns are REQUIRED and table is not empty. But after run the query, all columns mode change NULLABLE. My cast query like :

`SELECT
   CAST(id AS STRING) as id, column1, column2
 FROM
   dataset.mytable;`

Is it always that way, or I'm making a mistake?

Comment: What happens if you set the destination table to a new table, rather than overwriting the source table - do you get the desired results? Since you cannot change the data types in a table (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745229/how-can-i-change-a-date-field-from-string-to-date-or-datetime/53745854#53745854) I would not expect the overwrite function to work in this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm making a mistake?

Nope, it is by design, when you overwrite table original schema is lost and columns are nullable by default

> Is it always that way?

You should use [`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#syntax) DDL statement to achieve your goal. Something like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.mytable` (
  id STRING NOT NULL,
  column1 INT64 NOT NULL,
  column2 INT64 NOT NULL
) AS 
SELECT  CAST(id AS STRING) as id, column1, column2
FROM `project.dataset.mytable`
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works fine. But, partitioned by ingestion time tables do not work this way.how can i overwrite these tables ?